# How to define a collection of stack objects?

Tags: c++11

I am wondering if I can define a set of stack objects inside as part of list or vector? What I am trying to do is defining a collection of stack objects which I can get and add like normal int or float type inside one of STL containers. 
For example: `vector<stack> stackCollection` But it gives me error:
use of class template 'stack' requires template arguments.

Is there any way to do this in c++?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<stack> stackCollection;
    //vector<int> stackCollection;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hand over the actual code.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify which type the stack should contain, like this:

```
vector<stack<int>> stackCollection;
```

Comment: Thank you @Johannes